# Why is drop not called for a logger implementation?

Tags: logging, rust, destructor

I'm trying to use the log crate and implement a logger myself. I call it `mylog`.

```
extern crate log;
use log::*;

struct Mylog;

impl log::Log for Mylog {
    fn enabled(&self, metadata: &LogMetadata) -> bool {
        metadata.level() <= LogLevel::Info
    }

    fn log(&self, record: &LogRecord) {
        if self.enabled(record.metadata()) {
            println!("hello log");
        }
    }
}
impl Drop for Mylog {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("dropped"); // This is never called, why?
    }
}
pub fn init() -> Result<(), SetLoggerError> {
    log::set_logger(|max_log_level| {
        max_log_level.set(LogLevelFilter::Info);
        Box::new(Mylog)
    })
}
```

And in main.rs:

```
extern crate mylog;
#[macro_use] extern crate log;

fn main() {
    mylog::init().unwrap();
    info!("My info message");
}
```

`Drop` is never called and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The logger implementation is given to the logging library and [is effectively leaked](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/log/blob/0.3.6/src/lib.rs#L656-L659). This allows the implementation to act *as if* it has the `'static` lifetime, letting it be used in many places.

If you really need it, you can shut down the logger at the end of the program:

```
fn main() {
    mylog::init().unwrap();
    info!("My info message");
    log::shutdown_logger();
}
```

Comment: Note: I was curious about the thread-safety of this call so went looking into it; from what I understand the implementation maintains a counter of how many threads are currently logging and will "block" on the `shutdown_logger` call until all are done.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yeah, I was surprised at the implementation with the transmute and the underlying atomics.

Comment: It help if i call it myself. But i need catch when program finished with some error or killed. Or i need use panic catcher [link](https://github.com/sfackler/rust-log-panics/blob/master/src/lib.rs)?

Comment: @YuriNasyrov *when the program finishes with some error or is killed* — you simply cannot do anything when the program is killed; that's what killing a process means. As for when the program finishes with an error, that's harder to describe. Either you will have something like a `Result` and you can shutdown the logger, or the thread will have panicked. If it's a panic, then a panic handler might be useful, but you have to be pretty careful about anything you do in there.

Comment: As of 2024, this method does not exist any more. I had to implement a custom method on my logger.